# Fix stuttering with fixed time step and interpolation

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, interpolation

I am trying to fix my stuttering by using a fixed time step, but I seem to be missing something because it is not working.

Can someone look at this and see what is missing?

```
private static final float FIXED_TIME_STEP = 1 / 60f;
private float accumulator;

public void render() {
    super.render();
    final float deltaTime = Math.min(0.25f, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    accumulator += deltaTime;
    while(accumulator >= FIXED_TIME_STEP) {
        world.step(FIXED_TIME_STEP, 6, 2);
        accumulator -= FIXED_TIME_STEP;
    }

    gameRenderer.render(accumulator / FIXED_TIME_STEP);
}
```

Comment: "isn't working" is not a very good description.

Comment: As Raildex points out, there are lots of ways for this code to "not work" — anything from having a slight jitter to making your computer catch fire. Can you describe the patient's symptoms in more detail? These are often useful clues to diagnose the underlying cause. It would also help to see how your `gameRenderer.render(t)` method uses the interpolation weight you've given it as an argument. I also see you're calling a superclass's `render()` function — what class is that?

Comment: How much time does it take to render a frame, how much time does it take to perform a step?